# '--dependendy=aftercorr:Submitted' slurm option unrecognized

Tags: jobs, slurm

I have a script to run in slurm. The script works with **job-array aftercorr**, or at least that's what I want it to do. Basically it runs the first Job-array without any issue, however, it does not recognize the command **--dependendy=aftercorr**. I am quite new with slurm, could you please help me to understand the reason for this error. Is an error due the OS not having the command available?  or perhaps an error in my script?

Below are the main lines of the bash script, followed by the error I receive.

```
$ArrayAID=$(sbatch --array=1-5  Job_0.sh)
echo "Job-Array (script_0) id: ${ArrayAID}"

sbatch --array=1-5 --dependendy=aftercorr:$ArrayAID Job_1.sh
```

Output:

```
sbatch: unrecognized option '--dependendy=aftercorr:'
Try "sbatch --help" for more information
```

Cynthia

I tried running it in interactive mode and also searched bash for --help, but it hasn't been very informative. I'm also trying to see what's on the internet but I still don't have it.

Answer (score 1):

You are consistently spelling `--dependency` as `--dependendy` in the post. I will assume that is a typo only present in the StackOverflow messages.

The output of

```
$ArrayAID=$(sbatch --array=1-5  Job_0.sh)
```

will be that `ArrayAID` will contain `Submitted job XXXXX` where `XXXXX` is the job ID, and `$ArrayAID` will be expanded into `Submitted`. As a consequence, the next line will read something like

```
sbatch --array=1-5 --dependendy=aftercorr:Submitted Job_1.sh
```

which is an error as Slurm is expecting a job ID rather than the word 'Submitted'.

Add the `--parsable` option to the first `sbatch call`:

```
$ArrayAID=$(sbatch --parsable --array=1-5  Job_0.sh)
```

With that option, `sbatch` will only output the job ID (and also the cluster name if present ; in that case you will have to further adapt the line) and `ArrayAID` will contain the expected job ID

Comment: Thanks @damienfrancois, I had missed the **parsable** option to capture the ArrayAID. :)

Comment: If you feel that answers your question please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Thx

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the orientation. I will be able to solve this issue, by adding the **“–parsable”** option to **“sbatch command”**, with this option the job ID would be returned and its value can be stored in a shell variable for later use.

So, in the **first** **line** below, I am storing the corresponding **job-array ID** assigned for the slurm manager in the **ArrayAID** variable, as I am requesting **5 tasks** from index 1 to 5 (**--array=1-5**), I will have one job-array ID by task.

Then, on the **4th line**, I am evaluating the type of dependency, in this case I am conditioning that next job can only be submitted when the correlated job was completed successfully. There is a bunch of options for the condition, so you need to check what kind of dependency you want to have.

I wrote some scripts with samples explaining more details about **job-array dependencies**, please feel free to explore or let me know anything related to this repo. I am pretty new on this too.

https://github.com/cyntsc/Slurm_dependecies

Regards,
CSC

This are the new lines:

```
ArrayAID=$(sbatch --parsable --array=1-5  Job_0.sh)
echo "Job-Array. ID: ${ArrayAID}"
echo ""
sbatch --array=1-5 --dependency=aftercorr:${ArrayAID} Job_1.sh
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).